# running a program and keep track of its file system changes on unix

Tags: unix, filesystems

I'm searching for a way on unix to run a program in a certain way, so I can see when it exits what changes it did to the file system, like "CREATED /home/foo/bar.txt" or "CHANGED /home/foo/bar.txt". When you know a library/module that does this I would prefer if it supports C++, Python or Shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do - is to trace program system calls and then analyze them. 
For example, running an application with strace and catch open and write syscalls:

```
$ strace -e trace=open,write ./$APP_NAME
```